# FileVault Passkey Question

Tags: filevault

Helping a friend with their computer. They are running macOS 10.9 with FileVault2. Some "helpful" person turned FileVault on for them, even though they have no need for it. It is now preventing us from booting in SafeMode, Cloning their drive for upgrading to SSD, etc. They are not sure if they have the Passkey, but have a few things written down that MIGHT be the Passkey.

Question: If I turn FileVault OFF, try these various Passkeys, and none of them work, can I just cancel the process of turning FileVault OFF and they will be able to carry on as before?

Or is turning FV OFF and failing to provide the correct Passkey somehow going to cause a problem? (I know this is unlikely, and that I can probably just hit "cancel", but I dont want to risk hosing their system, so asking here.)

Thank you.

Comment: It's not preventing any of those things, just FYI.  And everyone should use FV.  I'd be much more concerned about them using an OS that isn't receiving security updates any longer.

Comment: Why not boot the existing OS and use an admin account and password to modify FileVault settings?